# ¿Cómo hacer consultas a array de json en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, json, array

Buen día.

Tengo el siguiente json: `[{"Name": "Bart", "Age": 10, "Id": 1}, {"Name": "Lisa", "Age": 8, "Id": 2}]`

Y necesito obtener la ruta cuantdo el Id es 2.

Yo se que con JSON_SEARCH puedo obtener rutas, pero con el Id no meda :(.

Si lo hago con el nombre si da así:

```
SELECT '[{"Name": "Bart", "Age": 10, "Id": 1}, {"Name": "Lisa", "Age": 8, "Id": 2}]' as json, 
   JSON_SEARCH('[{"Name": "Bart", "Age": 10, "Id": 1}, {"Name": "Lisa", "Age": 8, "Id": 2}]', 'one', 'Lisa') as path;
```

Y me sale el resultado esperado:

```
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|------------|
|json                                                                         | path       |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|------------|
|[{"Name": "Bart", "Age": 10, "Id": 1}, {"Name": "Lisa", "Age": 8, "Id": 2}]  |"$[1].Name" |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|------------|
```

Pero al intentarlo con el id asi:

```
SELECT '[{"Name": "Bart", "Age": 10, "Id": 1}, {"Name": "Lisa", "Age": 8, "Id": 2}]' as json, 
       JSON_SEARCH('[{"Name": "Bart", "Age": 10, "Id": 1}, {"Name": "Lisa", "Age": 8, "Id": 2}]', 'one', 2) as path;
```

Sale nulo:

```
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|------------|
|json                                                                         | path       |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|------------|
|[{"Name": "Bart", "Age": 10, "Id": 1}, {"Name": "Lisa", "Age": 8, "Id": 2}]  | null       |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|------------|
```

¿Cómo puedo realizar la consulta filtrando por id?

Muchas Gracias!

Comment: por favor agrega la version de mysql.

Comment: claro,la versión de MySQL es  5.7.31

Answer (score 1):

La función [JSON_SEARCH(json_doc, one_or_all, search_str[, escape_char[, path] ...])](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html) espera en su tercer parámetro un valor texto (string).

Un opción, quizás algo compleja, es la siguiente (evaluar posibles problemas de desempeño/performance):

```sql
SELECT
  JSON_SEARCH(
    REPLACE(
      REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
          JSON_EXTRACT(@`json`, "$[*].Id"),
          ', ',
          '","'
        ),
        '[',
        '["'
      ),
      ']',
      '"]'
    ),
    'one',
    '2'
  ) `path`;
```

Ver [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=aa4c4d83ce71a573e7392da6131a59f4).